# Carry Forward First Observation for a Variable For Each Patient

Tags: r, dataset, data-manipulation

My dataset has 3 variables:

```
Patient ID    Outcome     Duration  
1               1          3
1               0          4
1               0          5
2               0          2
3               1          1
3               1          2
```

What I want is the first observation for "Duration" for each patient ID to be carried forward.

That is, for patient #1 I want duration to read 3,3,3 for patient #3 I want duration to read 1, 1.

Comment: `dd$Duration <- with(dd, ave(Duration, ID, FUN = function(x) x[1]))` or the answers below if you want to use packages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative using `plyr` (if you will be doing lots of operations on your dataframe though, and particularly if it's big, I recommend `data.table`. It has a steeper learning curve but well worth it).

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mydf, .(PatientID), transform, Duration=Duration[1])  PatientID 
# Outcome Duration
# 1         1       1        3
# 2         1       0        3
# 3         1       0        3
# 4         2       0        2
# 5         3       1        1
# 6         3       1        1
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way with data.table. You take the first number in `Duration` and ask R to repeat it for each `PatientID`.

```
mydf <- read.table(text = "PatientID    Outcome     Duration  
1               1          3
1               0          4
1               0          5
2               0          2
3               1          1
3               1          2", header = T)

library(data.table)
setDT(mydf)[, Duration := Duration[1L], by = PatientID]
print(mydf)

#   PatientID Outcome Duration
#1:         1       1        3
#2:         1       0        3
#3:         1       0        3
#4:         2       0        2
#5:         3       1        1
#6:         3       1        1
```

Comment: Your output has `(1, 1, 3)` for the first row followed by `(1, 0, 3)`.  Is there a typo here or is this what you intended your code to do?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I am confused. Could you clarify what you mean? I see that the first row has `(1, 1, 3)` in the original data in the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If I am not mistaken, it is what the OP asked for.

Comment: Fair enough...I will upvote then...just wish these questions could be clearer, but then again if they were they probably would not be asking on SO in the first place ^ ^.  I thought he just wanted to duplicate the first row of each patient.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Not a typo, there are repeated observations for the same patient at different times. Some patients have more visits than others.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good job for `dplyr` (a data.frame wicked-better successor to `plyr` with far better syntax than `data.table`):

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(`Patient ID`) %>% 
  mutate(Duration=first(Duration))

## Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
## Groups: Patient ID
## 
##   Patient ID Outcome Duration
## 1          1       1        3
## 2          1       0        3
## 3          1       0        3
## 4          2       0        2
## 5          3       1        1
## 6          3       1        1
```